# Selenium WebDriver NullPointer exception in Java POM Class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, pageobjects

I've written two Java classes in my Selenium WebDriver script; One is POM Class in  which I've identified all the webpage elements like firstName and lastName, email etc.... Other class is my test class where I'm passing the values from my Excel sheets. When Executing my script, the TestClass is showing **NullPointerException** in the last @Test method. 
I'm trying to get the test data from the excel sheet (Say for Eg; FirstName)  & I'm sending it to the firstName input box by using the POM Class object. But the test fails with the NullPointerException

My POMClass.Java :

```
package com.datadriventest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class POMClass
{
    WebDriver driver;


    public POMClass(WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        driver = webDriver;
    }

    By regLink = By.linkText("REGISTER");
    By firstName = By.name("firstName");//----> Identifying firstName element in POM Class.
    By lastName = By.name("lastName");
    By phone = By.name("phone");
    By addressFirstLine = By.name("address1");
    By addressSecondLine = By.name("address2");
    By city = By.name("city");
    By state = By.name("state");
    By postalCode = By.name("postalCode");
    By country = By.name("country");
    By email = By.name("email");
    By password = By.name("password");
    By confirmPassword = By.name("confirmPassword");
    By regSubmit = By.name("register");

    public void goToRegLink()
    {
        driver.findElement(regLink).click();
    }


    public void setFirstName(String fname)//-->POM class method to send the firstName from testClass
    {
        driver.findElement(firstName).sendKeys(fname);
    }

    public void setLastName(String lname)
    {
        driver.findElement(lastName).sendKeys(lname);
    }

    public void setPhone(String phoneNo)
    {
        driver.findElement(phone).sendKeys(phoneNo);
    }

    public void setAddressFirstLine(String firstAddress)
    {
        driver.findElement(addressFirstLine).sendKeys(firstAddress);
    }

    public void setAddressSecondLine(String secondAddress)
    {
        driver.findElement(addressSecondLine).sendKeys(secondAddress);
    }

    public void setCity(String cityString)
    {
        driver.findElement(city).sendKeys(cityString);
    }

    public void setState(String stateString)
    {
        driver.findElement(state).sendKeys(stateString);
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String code)
    {
        driver.findElement(postalCode).sendKeys(code);
    }

    public void setCountry(String countryString)
    {
        WebElement countryDD = driver.findElement(country);
        Select dropDown = new Select(countryDD);
        dropDown.selectByVisibleText(countryString);

    }

    public void setEmail(String emailAddress)
    {
        driver.findElement(email).sendKeys(emailAddress);
    }

    public void setPassword(String passwordString)
    {
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(passwordString);
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confPassword)
    {
        driver.findElement(confirmPassword).sendKeys(confPassword);
    }

    public void clickRegBtn()
    {
        driver.findElement(regSubmit).click();
    }
}
```

My TestClass.Java:

```
package com.datadriventest;

import com.mavconfig.excel.utility.Xls_Reader;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.DriverManagerType;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManager;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.FirefoxDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DataDrivenClass

{
    WebDriver driver;
    POMClass pomClass;
    WebElement waitElement;
    Xls_Reader dataReader;
    String firstName,lastName,phone,email,address1,address2,city,state,postalCode,country,userName,password,confirmPassword;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"browser"})
    void browserSetup(String browser)
    {
        if (browser.equals("Chrome"))
        {
            ChromeDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.CHROME).setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        else if (browser.equals("Firefox"))
        {
            FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.FIREFOX).setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({"url"})
    void launchURL(String url)
    {
        System.out.println(url);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Test
    void goToRegPage()
    {
        waitElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER"));
        waitforVisiblity(driver, waitElement,15);

        if (waitElement.isDisplayed())
        {
            pomClass = new POMClass(driver);----> Here's the place where i'm declaring the pomclass by passing the testclass driver instance as constructor for the POM Class..

            pomClass.goToRegLink();//--> This click event is working fine,
        }
    }

    @Test
    void getExcelData()
    {
        dataReader = new Xls_Reader("C:\\Backup\\Selenium - Workspace\\IdeaProjects\\MavenSeleniumConfig\\src\\test\\java\\com\\testdata\\testData.xlsx");

        firstName = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","firstname",2);
        System.out.println("The first name is " +firstName);

         lastName = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","lastname",2);
         System.out.println("The last name is  : " +lastName);
         phone = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","phone",2);
         System.out.println("The Phone Number  : " +phone);
         email = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","email",2);
         System.out.println("The email address is  : " +email);
         address1 = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","Address1",2);
         System.out.println("The First Address Line is  : " +address1);
         address2 = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","Address2",2);
         System.out.println("The Second Address Line is  : " +address2);
         city = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","city",2);
         System.out.println("The City is  : " +city);
         state = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","state",2);
         System.out.println("The State is  : " +state);
         postalCode = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","postalcode",2);
         System.out.println("The postal code is  : " +postalCode);
         country = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","country",2);
         System.out.println("The Country is  : " +country);
         userName = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","username",2);
         System.out.println("The Username is  : " +userName);
         password = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","password",2);
         System.out.println("The password is  : " +password);
         confirmPassword = dataReader.getCellData("RegData","confirmpassword",2);
         System.out.println("The confirm password is  : " +confirmPassword);
    }

    @Test
    void fillTheForm()
    {
        pomClass.setFirstName(firstName);//------> This is the place I'm trying to send the firstName value to the input textfield, which shows NullPointerException.

    }
    @AfterClass
    void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }

    private void waitforVisiblity(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int timeout)
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }
}
```

My LogCat :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=56527:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\testng\lib\testng-rt.jar;C:\Backup\Selenium - Workspace\IdeaProjects\MavenSeleniumConfig\target\test-classes;C:\Backup\Selenium - Workspace\IdeaProjects\MavenSeleniumConfig\target\classes;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.141.59\selenium-java-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.141.59\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.141.59\selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.141.59\selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.141.59\selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.141.59\selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.141.59\selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.141.59\selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.141.59\selenium-support-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\25.0-jre\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.11.0\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.0\okio-1.14.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\io\github\bonigarcia\webdrivermanager\4.0.0\webdrivermanager-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.6\gson-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.10\commons-lang3-3.10.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\client5\httpclient5\5.0\httpclient5-5.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5\5.0\httpcore5-5.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5-h2\5.0\httpcore5-h2-5.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.13\commons-codec-1.13.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\rauschig\jarchivelib\1.0.0\jarchivelib-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.13.1\jsoup-1.13.1.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.14.3\testng-6.14.3.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.72\jcommander-1.72.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache-extras\beanshell\bsh\2.0b6\bsh-2.0b6.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\4.0.0\poi-ooxml-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\4.0.0\poi-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.2\commons-collections4-4.2.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\4.0.0\poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\3.0.1\xmlbeans-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.18\commons-compress-1.18.jar;C:\Users\arunp\.m2\repository\com\github\virtuald\curvesapi\1.04\curvesapi-1.04.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\testng\lib\jcommander-1.27.jar" com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket56526 @w@C:\Users\arunp\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp C:\Users\arunp\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp



SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 25152
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 26, 2020 4:21:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C


http://newtours.demoaut.com





java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.datadriventest.DataDrivenClass.fillTheForm(DataDrivenClass.java:109)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)


The first name is Arunprasadh
The last name is  : S
The Phone Number  : 7.402191727E9
The email address is  : arunprasadh.s@gmail.com
The First Address Line is  : Naval nagar, Vennaimalai(PO)
The Second Address Line is  : Karur
The City is  : Karur
The State is  : Tamil Nadu
The postal code is  : 639006.0
The Country is  : INDIA
The Username is  : Arun
The password is  : arun1234
The confirm password is  : arun1234






===============================================
My Maven Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please do let me know where I've committed the mistake, Anticipating for your responses.

Comment: It is better to declare the `pomClass` in a beforeClass method. And dont add `@Test` annotation to `getExcelData()` method, because you are not testing anything there. Run `getExcelData()` as a beforeClass method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fillTheForm()` test method get executed before `goToRegPage()` test method

If you haven't set execution order, test methods are executed in alphabetical order.

Set priority in each test method in the order you want to them to be executed;

```
@Test(priority=2)
void goToRegPage()

@Test(priority=1) // You can add priority=0. 0 Has the highest priority
void getExcelData()

@Test(priority=3)
void fillTheForm()
```